# Systemd service name with spaces

Tags: web-services, systemd

I have created in /etc/systemd/system the following service - my test.service , however when I try to start the service via `systemctl start "my test.service"` the service does not get started and it is not found.How can I escape the name of the service if it contains spaces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. `systemd.unit(5)` clearly states what characters are allowed in unit names.

Comment: can you cite please where this is mentioned exactly?

Comment: My bad. I (stupidly) assumed that the man pages and the online documentation would be identical. Look in https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html and search for ASCII

Answer (score 2):

> Valid unit names consist of a "name prefix" and a dot and a suffix specifying the unit type. The "unit prefix" must consist of one or more valid characters (ASCII letters, digits, ":", "-", "_", ".", and ""). The total length of the unit name including the suffix must not exceed 256 characters. The type suffix must be one of ".service", ".socket", ".device", ".mount", ".automount", ".swap", ".target", ".path", ".timer", ".slice", or ".scope".

Source (noted by JayEye): https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html